# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Phone'

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, get

I have an error:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Phone'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Order(Int32[], Int32[], System.String,
>   Int32, System.String, Int32, System.String, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String)' in 'Shop.Controllers.HomeController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter."

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Order(int[] OrderProductCount, int[] OrderProductID, string AllName, int Phone, string Region, int MailIndex, string Email, string City, string MailType, string Additional=null)
     {
        return View("Order");
    }
```

I can't understand where is error, because when i set form method attribute to get, it had Phone value:

```
http://localhost:2420/Order?AllName=asdasd&Email=asdsaasd%40asd&City=sdafsdaf&Region=dsfasda&Phone=380983050430&MailIndex=100005&Additional=&MailType=%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC&OrderProductID=53&OrderProductCount=32&OrderProductID=52&OrderProductCount=12
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling the `Order` action in your Controller?

Comment: have you tried chaning Phone to String in the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone number(380xxxxxxxxx) is biggest that range of integer(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647).

Comment: therefore if you make that parameter a String it should work